# How do I create an interactive summation column in a table and graph it?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I have some local data that is structured as follows:

```
A   B   C   D   E   
1   0   0   1   0  
1   1   0   0   0  
2   0   1   1   2  
0   0   0   1   0  
1   0   3   1   0
```

Where each column contains only integers that represent a number of occurrences of that variable for a given observation. I want to create a column that sums each row while allowing me to add/remove the columns dynamically without needing a new equation for the summation. I want to do this so that we can see how adding/removing each variable affects the totals so that we can create a histogram of the number of rows with each number of occurrences. Currently I can only figure out how to make static "total" columns where I manually specify each column to sum but I'd rather just have a column that sums columns that exist in the table dynamically.

For example:
All columns:

```
A   B   C   D   E   Total
1   0   0   1   0   2
1   1   0   0   0   2
2   0   1   1   2   6
0   0   0   1   0   1
1   0   3   1   0   5
```

In this instance, I want to be able to create a histogram where there are 0 rows with 0 occurrences, 1 row with 1 occurrence, 2 rows with 2 occurrences, 0 rows with 3 & 4 occurrences, and 1 row each of 5 and 6 occurrences.

Only columns A, C, D included:

```
A   C   D   Total
1   0   1   2
1   0   0   1
2   1   1   4
0   0   1   1
1   3   1   5
```

In this instance, I want to be able to create a histogram where there are 0 rows with 0 occurrences, 2 rows with 1 occurrence, 1 rows with 2 occurrences, 1 row with 4 occurrences, and 1 row with 5 occurrences.

My real data has many more columns and rows so I want to be able to set up a table/cross table so that I can see the effects of adding and removing rows on the resulting histogram.

Please let me know if you have any questions regarding the data or the desired output and I'll give as much detail as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: add a Textarea, and in it put a new document property (call it e.g. sumcols) as a multiple choice list box. This defines sumcols as a string list. You will have to manually select the columns but otherwise you won't have to change the formula.

Then create a new calculated column Total as

$map("[${sumcols}]","+")

This creates a concatenated sum of all the columns you placed in sumcols.